# ActionBar-PullToRefresh with ActionBarSherlock

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, pull-to-refresh

I'm trying to use both libraries in my project but I'm getting the following error:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This HeaderTransformer is
>   designed to run on SDK 14+. If using ActionBarSherlock or
>   ActionBarCompat you should use the appropriate provided extra.

I downloaded the library ActionBar-PullToRefresh from here https://github.com/chrisbanes/ActionBar-PullToRefresh and Imported the folder library into my workspace. How do I import the folder extras to this project to get it work??

Im working in eclipse btw.

EDIT:

I copied the folder extras into the project but I get errors in one of the files as shown below:

[image]

EDIT 2:
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to import both projects:
The ActionBar-PullToRefresh main project (is the library folder) **AND** the ActionBar-PullToRefresh for ActionBarSherlock. You must import this folder ActionBar-PullToRefresh/library/extras/actionbarsherlock as Android Project into eclipse.
Than you have to add the dependencies to this Project:
1) ActionBar-PullToRefresh (the main library)
2) ActionBarSherlock

To do so, you have to do a right click on the imported project --> Properties --> Android --> Libraries section (add button).

Than you have to add this imported library to your Android App Project

Comment: I did what you said but still have errors in the file AbsDefaultHeaderTransformer.java. I edited the question with a new pic

Comment: Sorry, turned out that I was using an old library thats why I get the errors.Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to use the compatibility version instead. It will be in the same project you were using. You just need to change the imported file from

```
import uk.co.senab.actionbarpulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshAttacher;
```

to

```
import uk.co.senab.actionbarpulltorefresh.extras.actionbarcompat.PullToRefreshAttacher;
```

Comment: when I import the library into workspace, the folder extras is not there. So I copy this folder and put in into the src project like the picture in my question. But I get many errors in the file AbsDefaultHeaderTransformer. I also import the sherlock library into this one. Is this the correct form to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You might have cloned the project which might be unstable. Download one of the stable release from here https://github.com/chrisbanes/ActionBar-PullToRefresh/releases

I personally use v0.8 No issues yet.